# share some value between callbacks matlab GUI

Tags: matlab

i have four variables which two of them,named 'lat' and 'long' get value in a popup, and two others, named 'lat1' and 'long1', which get value in the same way in a different popup menu and this four, finally would be used in a third popup menu.

first i tried global variables but didn't work at all, then i tried handles structures and read every thing about it and read everything about sharing data and value between functions and callbacks and every question in stack overflow around this topic but it didn't help me.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: someone has posted her whole code and has been fooled beautifully and you're showing-off your Grammars talents? is that how you got that reputation or it's just you don't know how to spent your time?! :))

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Most people prefer not to appear ignorant. I have simply informed you not to use "Thanks" at all, here, and I was nice enough to let you know that you spelled it wrong. Now you know, and you can choose not to spell it wrong in the future.

Comment: so let us hope it would be the last time you intrude into something you have no idea about! that's what MOST PEOPLE do!

Comment: Are you complaining about the fact that I edited your question to remove "Thanks in advanced", or are you complaining that I informed you "BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced"."?

Comment: it just about people who edit a question for a "d" word and leave negative comment to get some reputation

Comment: I get no reputation when I edit a question. I also did not leave a negative comment. I provided you with some information which you can use or ignore. I don't actually _care_ whether you spell "Advance" correctly or  not. I thought that _you_ might care whether or not you appear to be ignorant. Certainly, I have noticed that many people have a negative impression about people who do not spell correctly. It leaves them with the false impression that such people are not intelligent. They are mistaken about that, but I thought I'd help you to appear less ignorant. Sorry if that offends you.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know exactly what you need from your description, but I'll guess that you have a main GUI and are using separate pop-ups to get inputs? I think from what you have said, you are on the right track.

The handles variable is what you want. It is really useful for sharing data throughout a GUI (if you have used [GUIDE](http://uk.mathworks.com/videos/creating-a-gui-with-guide-68979.html) to set up your GUI environment then handles should be available, if not then you will have to set it up yourself by calling `guihandles` - [more details here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html)). If you save your variables into it, e.g.

`handles.long = ...`, `handles.lat = ...`

and update the variables with `guidata(hObject,handles)` then you should be able to access `handles.long` and `handles.lat` throughout your GUI.

Comment: i replaced all the 'lat' and 'long' with 'handles.long' and 'handles.lat' but I'm puzzled, i doesn't work.

Comment: And i want to save 4 value but it seems i can do it only for one time! :-(

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing the code. Could you post it?